# Getting a Parameter and Using it as an Array Name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a bunch of arrays named a=[], b=[], c=[], d=[], and so on.
A Table is shown to the client and depending on the cell that the client clicks, we do operations to the specific array made for that cell.
The code explains what I mean in a better way.
I would be thankful if anyone helps.
HTML:

```
<td id="block1" class="blocks" onclick="markNLock('a',this)" onmouseover="setMouseOverColor(this)" onmouseout="setMouseOutColor(this)">
```

Js:

```
function markNLock(idx, mark) {
    for(var i=0; i<Matrix.length; i++)
    {
        Matrix[i] += idx[i];
        console.log(idx[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: your problems are caused by using mid 90's style inline event handlers.   If you write your code using `addEventListener` instead this problem won't happen.

Comment: Try telling what exactly is the problem and Half the stuff is not told

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer the problem is obvious - the OP is passing a string for the array name, and wants to access the array of that particular name.

Comment: Why don't you remove the string tag and instead pass in `a` instead of `"a"`. Problem solved

Comment: NB: having a bunch of arrays of (presumed) identical purpose but with different names is an indication of poor design.    Variable names are not the way to differentiate items like that - they should either be a two-D array, or an object where the keys are the "identifier" and the array is the value.

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer as Alnitak described, the problem is obvious.

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer no, that assumes (and requires) that `a` is a global variable, and therefore bad practise.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you for your advice. I apologize if my question was basic. I am a beginner and I will try to change the method to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't have enough information to propose a "correct" solution because it's unclear what controls which particular cell is going to access which array.   i.e. why is it that `blocks1` goes to array `a`?    Is it the only one?   Does `blocks2` go to array `b`?

Comment: @Alnitak Nevermind about the ids I just have to remove them. imagine there are 9 cells in order to make a tic-tac-toe game. based on this algorithm: https://majicdesigns.github.io/MD_TicTacToe/page_library.html

Comment: IDs do matter, because you need to have _some_ mechanism to identify which cell is which, especially if you want to programatically assign the event handlers.  It makes the difference between having a single function that can do the job for _every_ cell or having to repeat code for every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the other advice I've given, the most expedient fix for your problem is not to use separate arrays, but to use your strings `a`, `b` etc as *keys* into the lookup matrix:

```
const game_matrix = {
  'a': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  'b': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  ...
}
```

and you can then use your string parameter as an index into that object:

```
Matrix[i] += game_matrix[idx][i];
```